# Georeferencing a .jpg image

Tags: google-maps, georeferencing, jpg

I have a jpeg image of a district. I need to georeference it. The problem is that I am able to find only one control point of it. All other line features (are roads) are those which I am not able to match with Google since the boundary of my area and the area given in Google Maps differs. I am hereby attaching the image. Please help me to solve the issue

[image]

Comment: Hi, and the roads are also not present in google maps?

Comment: ya please tell me wat to do?

Answer (score 3):

Please try to find out known points or nodes which are matching to Google. Try at least 3 points from Google. I know it is very difficult case but go deeply with your map and google map. or try to find out any 3 corner points of a municipal boundary.  Another way is try to get a georeferenced map of your municipal corporation then try to rubber sheet it with georeference tool.

Answer (score 3):

Can you go into ArcMap and load one of the Basemap and then bring that jpg to it and use the Georeferencing toolbox ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use QGIS for this, here a tutorial which I have written for a similar problem: http://gis.cri.fmach.it/download/tutorials/geocoding_maps_from_articles.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Can't you look for bounaries which match to junktions of the roads and use it as pass points? Boundaries of quaters are normally build along transport ways.

Answer (score 1):

Arun ...Just check the Municipal boundary on google. may be zoom level will be different but u will get the X Y of 3 corner from it. Just check the unit of Google Maps if it is Degree decimal then change it ArcGis unit. Adjust the zoom level of Google maps of your area, may be Google having the Boundary of Municipal corporation area. just check it..

Thanks and Regards